# Angular Material Form autocomplete with 5000 values

Tags: angular, forms, autocomplete, angular-material

I am using Angular 7 and Angular Material.

I use the [autocomplete angular form material component](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) by storing the values ​​directly in my component.

Except that now, I would like to filter on more than 5000 values. If I store it directly in my component, I lose performance.

What is the strategy I need to adopt?

Comment: Try using API calls for filtering values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's case-specific really.
What I would suggest is the following:

Instead of automatically sorting all of your 5000 records at `ngOnInit`, wait until the user first types inside your auto-complete search bar. Once a letter is typed, perform an API call that would filter these records in the backend, returning a smaller portion of these records.

The rest of the filtering will then be performed on the frontend.

Comment: Hi i use firebase. 
I thought it would have been better to store my static array in the asset folder but you prefer in firebase? Do you have an example of implementation please?

Comment: So in your case it would be much simpler to simply filter them on the front-end.
In which case, your most convenient solution is finding the best practice to filter data based on its structure. Based on the wide variety of filtering techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You have to paging to load maximum is 20 elements when input any data to filter. And use debounce time and Subject to trigger input data and cancel observable.

Comment: Are you know paging in back-end  with param page and size?